# KeyError: "Stemming algorithm not found" using Snowballstemmer for Arabic

Tags: python, arabic, stemming, snowball, arabic-support

I installed this stemmer for arabic language [Here](http://www.arabicstemmer.com/python/). I was running it with this code :

```
from snowballstemmer import stemmer
ar_stemmer = stemmer("arabic")
ar_stemmer.stemWord(u"فسميتموها")
```

And when I run it, I get this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\CLIENT\Desktop\snowballstemmer-1.1.0.tar\snowballstemmer-   1.1.0\stemmer.py", line 9, in <module>
ar_stemmer = stemmer("arabic")
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\snowballstemmer\__init__.py", line 57,   in stemmer
raise KeyError("Stemming algorithm '%s' not found" % lang)
KeyError: "Stemming algorithm 'arabic' not found"
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't install the version of snowballstemmer from PyPi cause it doesn't support Arabic yet. Install the version provided in the [link](http://www.arabicstemmer.com/python/). It has [this Arabic stemmer](http://www.arabicstemmer.com/) inside. You can do this by downloading the tarball and execute the setup.py:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Here is an example:

```
>>> from snowballstemmer import stemmer
>>> ar_stemmer = stemmer("arabic")
>>> stem = ar_stemmer.stemWord(u"فسميتموها")
>>> print stem
سمي
>>> stem
u'\u0633\u0645\u064a'
```

Answer (score 1):

I once worked with SnowballStemmer, 
this was the way it worked for me:

```
>>> from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
>>> print(" ".join(SnowballStemmer.languages)) # See which languages are supported
danish dutch english finnish french german hungarian
italian norwegian porter portuguese romanian russian
spanish swedish
>>> stemmer = SnowballStemmer("german") # Choose a language
>>> stemmer.stem("Autobahnen") # Stem a word
'autobahn'
```

I'm not sure if arabic works here